# how to authenticate http request in axios

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, http, postman

I am using Axios on a node mjs script.
I am hitting a server that uses basic http authentication. on browser, if I hit

```
http://user:pass@192.168.254.4/api/endpoint1
```

it works and gives me the requested data
but when I use the same URL on Axios.get method it fails.

```
Unauthorized

This server could not verify that you are authorized to access the document requested. Either you supplied the wrong credentials (e.g., bad password), or your browser doesn't understand how to give the credentials required.
```

same thing on postman too (doesn't work on postman either).

am I missing something here?

Comment: Try using authentication header with Axios instead of appending credential in URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var session_url = 'http://api_address/api/session_endpoint';
var username = 'user'; var password = 'password';
var credentials = btoa(username + ':' + password);
var basicAuth = 'Basic ' + credentials;
axios.post(session_url, { headers: { 'Authorization': basicAuth } })
```

This will work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code:

```
var session_url = 'http://api_address/api/session_endpoint';
var username = 'user'; var password = 'password';
var credentials = btoa(username + ':' + password);
var basicAuth = 'Basic ' + credentials;
axios.post(session_url, { headers: { 'Authorization': + basicAuth } })
```

Comment: nope doesnt work, this gives me same error

Comment: data: '<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">\n' +
      '<html><head>\n' +
      '<title>401 Unauthorized</title>\n' +
      '</head><body>\n' +
      '<h1>Unauthorized</h1>\n' +
      '<p>This server could not verify that you\n' +
      'are authorized to access the document\n' +
      'requested.  Either you supplied the wrong\n' +
      'credentials (e.g., bad password), or your\n' +
      "browser doesn't understand how to supply\n" +
      'the credentials required.</p>\n' +
      '</body></html>\n'

Comment: do u think browser adds some internal protocol translation logic for this one? idk how it works on browser and not on plain http requests

Comment: @Xeno Can you try this: `axios.get("http://user:pass@192.168.254.4/api/endpoint1", { auth: { username: "user", password: "pass" }});`